# Wigner-Eckart theorem: Completeness relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory, wigner-eckart

Consider the Wigner-Eckart theorem given by
$$\langle \alpha' j m'|A^q|\alpha j m\rangle = \frac{\langle \alpha' j m'|\mathbf{J}\cdot\mathbf{A}|\alpha j m\rangle}{j(j+1)}\langle j m'| J^q|j, m\rangle$$

where $A^q$ is a tensor operator. Can something be said about the completeness relation for the states $|\alpha j m\rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

Your notation suggests that $j$ and $m$ index the rotation group representation vectors, which are of course complete. And for $\alpha$ you need to have just one value to apply the theorem, so whether you have constructed a combined set of states $|\alpha j m\rangle$, or whether it even exists, does not follow from it.